# Replacing an Excel nested IF by a vlookup of formula text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a spreadsheet for Materials Requirement Planning (just for fun). One problem is with lot-sizing rules. I have to use OFFSET and INDIRECT functions in a lot of places, and the formulas are exceedingly hard to read (and they are long!).

Is there any way to put the formula texts for different rules into an array and to select them based on a VLOOKUP? What I am hoping for is to find a function that does the following:

```
=FORMULAFROMTEXT(VLOOKUP(rule,$A1:$B5,formula, FALSE))
```

where rule might be one of "L4L", "FOQ", etc, and the table would look like

```
L4L     L4L-formula
FOQ     FOQ-formula
...
```

This looks a lot cleaner (and shorter) to me than

```
IF(rule="L4L",L4L-formula,IF(rule="FOQ",FOQ-formula,IF(...))).
```

Comment: You would put the result of `L4L-formula` and then just vlookup the result.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a function using VBA.

With your Excel sheet open, start the Visual Basic Editor by doing the following:

- **on a Windows PC**
  press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
- **on a Mac**
  press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

then click `Insert` then `Module`.

A new module window appears on the right-hand side of the Visual Basic Editor.

Copy the following into the new module window:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

You can now close the Visual Basic Editor as you have now created a `EVAL(cell reference)` formula function.

### Now to use this new function whilst using `VLOOKUP()` for the formula.

If the formula is to be built according to what row the data is in, for example,

```
      ¦  A  ¦  B  ¦    C    ¦
-----------------------------
   1  ¦  2  ¦  2  ¦  =A1+B1 ¦
-----------------------------
   2  ¦  4  ¦  2  ¦  =A2+B2 ¦
-----------------------------
```

and cells `C1` and `C2` is `L4L-formula`

Then you need to bear in mind the volatility of the formula.  You cannot just put A1+B1 for `L4L-formula` for example.  You would have to input **without the equals sign (=)** `"B"&ROW()&"+C"&ROW()` for `L4L formula`.

You will then need to create a helper column for the resulting formula.

If your formula list is as follows:

```
      ¦  A  ¦       B       ¦
-----------------------------
   1  ¦ L4L ¦  L4L-formula  ¦  Let's say this is F + G
-----------------------------
   2  ¦ FOQ ¦  FOQ-formula  ¦  Let's say this is F x G
-----------------------------
```

If `L4L-formula` is to be `F + G`, then as indicated before you need to input `"F"&ROW()&"+G"&ROW()` into cell `B1`

If `FOQ-formula` is to be `F x G` then you need to input `"F"&ROW()&"*G"&ROW()` into cell `B2`

Now if your worktable is on the same sheet and is as follows:

```
      ¦  F  ¦  G  ¦  H  ¦
-------------------------
   1  ¦  2  ¦  2  ¦ L4L ¦
-------------------------
   2  ¦  4  ¦  2  ¦ FOQ ¦
-------------------------
```

then put the following into cell `I1` and drag it down:

```
=EVAL(VLOOKUP(H1,A:B,2,FALSE))
```

Column `I` is now a helper column which builds the required formula for that row.  You can of course hide that column when printing (if required).

For the result of that formula, you would then put `=EVAL(I1)` into cell `J1` and you can drag that down too.